# no module named sumo.runner in mininet wifi installation

Tags: mininet

I am getting this error while working in **mininet**:

```
no module named sumo.runner error
```

This error occurred while i was working in mininet wifi installation. Kindly help me out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version do you have installed? It should work fine from 1.8r1. Please clone it from github.com/intrig-unicamp/mininet-wifi and run make install to update to the newest version.

Comment: Cloned it again but still getting the same error....Thanx for writing to my question....i would be greatfull to you could kindly provide some other solution to me

Comment: Hi, I just tried and it is working properly. Could you confirm the installed version (sudo mn --version)?